# Why does bash replaces text from command substitution with text thereafter

Tags: bash, cat, echo, command-substitution, for

I was trying to parse some nginx config

```
λ tree sites-enabled/ sites-available/
sites-enabled/
├── bank.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── calendar.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── cloud.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── cwrcoding.com.conf
├── drive.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── groups.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── mail.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── sites.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── studentenverwaltung.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── wekan.cwrcoding.com.conf
└── www.cwrcoding.com.conf
sites-available/
├── bank.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── calendar.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── cloud.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── cwrcoding.com.conf
├── drive.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── groups.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── mail.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── sites.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── studentenverwaltung.cwrcoding.com.conf
├── wekan.cwrcoding.com.conf
└── www.cwrcoding.com.conf
```

The sites-enabled/* files each contain a single line:

```
include sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf;
```

When trying to iterate over the sites-enabled/* files, cutting those and trying to read their contents as files, I got some weird error, so I tried a minimalistic working solution, and working my way up from there, but yet the following happens:

```
λ for enabled in sites-enabled/*
> do
> echo "$(cat "$enabled") |"
> echo ==========
> done
include sites-available/bank.cwrcoding.com.conf; |
==========
 |clude sites-available/calendar.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/cloud.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/drive.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/groups.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/mail.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/sites.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-available/studentenverwaltung.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
include sites-available/wekan.cwrcoding.com.conf; |
==========
 |clude sites-available/www.cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
```

As you can see, for most of the sites the first characters of the *cat* output are replaced by the text supposed to be *after* the command substitution.

Can anyone explain what is happening? Or have I found some bug?

If you want to take a look at the files: https://github.com/cwrau/nginx-config

Comment: This doesn't really solve the question you're asking, but depending on exactly how you want the output formatted, you might want to take a look at the `paste` program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your files have DOS/Windows-style line-endings.  As a quick work-around, replace:

```
echo "$(cat "$enabled") |"
```

With:

```
echo "$(tr -d '\r' <"$enabled") |"
```

Here, `tr` removes the carriage-return character before the file is displayed, avoiding the problem.

*If your files are intended to be used on a Unix system, however, you would be better off removing the carriage-returns from the files themselves using one the `dos2unix` or similar utilities.*

#### Example

Let's create two DOS-style files:

```
$ echo 'include sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf;' | unix2dos > sites-enabled/file1
$ echo 'include sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf;' | unix2dos > sites-enabled/file2
```

Let's run the original command:

```
$ for enabled in sites-enabled/*; do echo "$(cat "$enabled") |"; echo ==========; done
 |clude sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
 |clude sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf;
==========
```

Note the mangled output.

With `tr` applied, we receive the output that we expect:

```
$ for enabled in sites-enabled/*; do echo "$(tr -d '\r' <"$enabled") |"; echo ==========; done
include sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf; |
==========
include sites-availabe/cwrcoding.com.conf; |
==========
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it! Now to remove those pesky carriage-returns :D

Comment: Look into `dos2unix`.